# nervous mousepointer on mousemove

Tags: javascript, mouse

I have a problem with a specific use of javascript. On my development website https://famnabuurs.nl I prepared a simple page with three columns.

I manipulate the mousepointer... On the left and right side the cursor disappears by objective. When I move my mousepointer over the image in the center, the textblock should show up and then follow the mousepointer until the mousepointer leaves the image again.
The moving phase works fine as long as I move the mouse to the left side, but when I move the cursor from left to right over the image the mouse seems to get nervous. Also when I move from top to bottom it goes wrong. The textblock jumps from cursor-position to top of the image and back. 
I assume I made a mistake in the javascript, but no idea what causes this issue.
This is my relevant code, the part that follows the mousepointer:

```
function mousemovedimage(e) {  

const imageItSelf = document.getElementById(objectnaam); 
const titleblock = document.getElementById(objectnaam+'_id');  
      // on mouseover make the sheet visible
  var imageOffset = imageItSelf.getBoundingClientRect();        
  let xpos = e.clientX - imageOffset.left ;
  // do not shift too far to the right     
  if (xpos > imageItSelf.clientWidth) {
    titleblock.style.setProperty('display','none', 'important');
  } else {
      if (xpos < 0) {
      // do not shift too far to the left
      titleblock.style.setProperty('display','none', 'important');
      } else {
      titleblock.style.setProperty('display','block', 'important');
          titleblock.style.top = e.offsetY + 'px';
          titleblock.style.left = (xpos) + 'px';
      }
  }
}
```

This function is added as an eventListener:

```
objectnaam = 'roel-image-twee-eiken-desktop-tablet'; 
document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemovedimage);
```

The titleblock is the moving textblock.

Could someone give me a hint to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the pointer going over the text. Try setting `pointer-events: none` to the title. Something like:

```
titleblock.style.setProperty('pointer-events','none');
```

Comment: Great solution, and so easy. At least if you know it exists. Thanks for your hint